# Javascript nested objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying todo some OO in Javascript, and I'm coming from C++ and Ruby. I've managed to create one object, but nesting an object inside is being alittle bit of a pain.

```
function Model()
{
   //...
}

function Player(props)
{
   var props = {
      // ...
   }

   var model = new Model(props); // I've tried 'this.model = new Model() as well
}

var props = {
   // ...
}
var player = new Player(props);
```

Player gets created fine, but if I try and nest the object it fails. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/M2J8y/)

You were close. There are much better ways of "seudo-extending" object in javascript. [**jQuery.extend**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is one possible way. You can write your own method that check properties as well. I think the biggest break down for you was overwriting `props` in the `Player` function.

- With functions `this` is key
- Functions are the only scope in JavaScript, so be careful with naming variables
- It's important to understand the difference between the object literal `var a = {}` and functions `var a = new Method();`. However, it seems you have that down well.

## Code

```
function Model(data)
{
   this.Name = data.Name;
   this.Other = data.Other;
}

function Player(props)
{
   var privateProps = {
       Name: 'testing'
   };
   privateProps.Other = props.Other;
   this.model = new Model(privateProps); // I've tried 'this.model = new Model() as well
}

var props = {
    Other: 'Other'
}
var player = new Player(props);
```

​